# How to display login windows before display main windows

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt, qt-designer

Good Morning, I'm developing an app in PyQt, my problem is, that I have developed the main window and from that I run the login window, what I like to do now is, when running the program, the login window start first and, if the login is granted, display the main window

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside the function that initates the window, wrap the window initializer inside an `if` statement that checks for stored login credentials (however they are stored). If they don't exist or something, have the code jump to launching the login form, which will do its work and close. After that it's a matter of taste, but I'd have the function that initiates the window called again, nested inside.

Comment: Thank you very much.. I'll give it a try and let you know

Comment: If this works for you, don't forget to mark best answer. Although, almost certainly, someone will come along and vote a better answer than mine.